# Java Hibernate use of case when else query resulting exception in hql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Use of this query:

### Need to get the minimum rank for the keywordIds where rank is not equal to 0 searchengine is "xyz.com" and, if a keywordId has no rank other than 0 then it should show as 10000

**TrackId** | **KeywordId** | **SearchEngine** | **Rank**

1        |         101   |        xyz.com   |  0

1        |         101   |        xyz.com   |  55

1        |         101   |        xyz.com   |  12

2        |         201   |        xyz.com   |  1

2        |         201   |        xyz.com   |  98

2        |         201   |        xyz.com   |  23

3        |         301   |        xyz.com   |  0

3        |         301   |        xyz.com   |  0

---

Result should be:

**min Rank**

---

12

```
1
```

10000

---

When I am using the hql query as below the result I am getting is getting exception :

```
bestRanks[i] = (List<Integer>)getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam("Select min(case when Rank > 0 then Rank else 10000 end) from Serpstrackhistory t where t.keywordId in (:KeywordId) and t.searchEngine=(:SearchEngine) group by KeywordId ORDER BY FIELD(KeywordId,t.keywordId in (:KeywordIds))",new String[]{"KeywordId", "SearchEngine", "KeywordIds"}, new Object[]{keywordId ,searchEngine[i], keywordId});
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
 \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'min'
    \-[CASE] CaseNode: 'case'
       +-[WHEN] SqlNode: 'when'
       |  +-[GT] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '>'
       |  |  +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'Rank' {originalText=Rank}
       |  |  \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '0'
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'Rank' {originalText=Rank}
       \-[ELSE] SqlNode: 'else'
          \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '10000'
```

When I am using the raw query as below the result I am getting is correct:

```
SELECT min(case when Rank > 0 then Rank else 10000 end) FROM `serpstrackhistory` WHERE  KeywordId in (1,2,3) and SearchEngine="xyz.com" group by KeywordId
```

Please help me to know what is incorrect in my hql query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the query with aliases -

```
min(case when t.Rank > 0 then t.Rank else 10000 end)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes the issue went off by aliasing, but now getting java null pointer exception in the HQL line , and no other info provided in console.

Comment: please tell what is the proper syntax for using order by field in hql

Comment: @subhajit Try using this - ORDER BY FIELD(t.keywordId, :KeywordIds)